# Mapcanvas not showing layers features

Tags: qgis, mapcanvas

usually when i load an osm file with lots of features (>10000) the qgis will go not responding,

when the files loaded, layers will show up, but not the features on the map canvas, its just blank

sometimes 1 or more layers will show its content,
but theres always a layers or more wont

i need to restart the notebook so the contents will show, but it will happen again if i try to open another project

problems only occur when add new vector layer with osm files,
loading shp files or old project is okay